# define whether index of an element equals to variable

Tags: jquery, variables, indexing, equals

I need to compare the value of the variable and index of an element. If they are equal then select an element with this index and perform an action on it's children. the value of the variable is not constant, when the user moves from new-set to new-set, the variable + 1.

```
var nextclix = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
...if (){
nextclix++;}
}
```

html

```
 <div class="new-set">
....
</div>
<div class="new-set">
 ....
</div>
```

I have searched for hours on google and this forum, but with no result for so far...

Could anybody please give a hint???

Edit:

This is a kind of game where the user goes though a number of sets (one at a time on the screen), ".new-set". When 1 set is completed, the user goes to the next "new-set". nextclix is a variable that counts the "new-sets", null based. So when the user is on the "new-set"[0], the nextclix = 0,
then the user clicks the button next, he goes to the "new-set"[1] and the nextclix=1....

However in each new-set may be a different number of questions. like in the 1st -3 questions and in the 2nd - 5 questions

So my target is to get the script count the number of the items in each "new-set" based on the number of "new-set" index. numObjects is a variable that counts the number of answers, when all answers are given a user may go to the next "new-set"

I have this script to count the nr of items:

```
var NewSetArray = $('.new-set');    
var numObjects = $(NewSetArray[nextclix]).find(Answer).length;
```

But it works only for the first ""new-set"[0] which appears first on the screen. When I click on the "next" button, the numObjects stays at the value for the "new-set"[0]

nextclix count properly.

It would be something simple, but I don't see it...

Any ideas???

Comment: sadly,you did not reveal any of your code

Comment: Please add some more context. Or, better, some JSFiddle

Comment: What is `nextclix` being matched to for the index? And what does `new-set` divs represent?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't place more code.... But I have added more content. Thank you all :-)

Comment: What is "Answer"? Why are you trying to find its length?

Comment: Answer is an array of ".answer" - the answers to be given. When all of the answers are given a user may go to the next "new-set"

Comment: So I need to know a number of ".answer" for each particular new-set when a user is on it(or probbably moment when it should happen user clicks on the button"next", goes to the next "new-set")

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you can write:

```
var setArray = document.getElementsByClassName('new-set');
```

But since you are using Jquery you could just write:

```
var setArray = $('.new-set');
```

The variable setArray will now hold an array of elements. Remember this will be 0 based so if your index (i.e. nextclix) is not 0 based you will need to subtract 1 to align it with the setArray.

If your div classes are loaded just once (i.e. you aren't creating elements with the 'new-set' class either by ajax or user input after the page has loaded) then your code COULD look something like this:

```
var setArray = $('.new-set');

function highlightChildrenIfEqual(value, index){
    if(value==index){
        $(setArray[index]).children().addClass('highlight');
    }
}
```

That function would just compare value and index. If they are equal it would apply a highlight class (which you would have to define yourself to all of the children of the 'new-set' with the specified index.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have brought me by some ideas :-) (see the edit above) but I'm still struggling with this one... I'm missing something...